# Method to get the weight of all graph edges

Tags: java, graph

I have to make a method that returns the distance of path whose vertices are defined in a class called 'IglesiaImpl' and given as parameters. I've thought about creating a new graph with those vertices and use getEdgeWeight() but would it work?.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 'but would it work' - how should we know. I do not have access to your code (`IglesiaImpl` and 'getEdgeWeight'). You might want to post an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Are you just wondering about how to define your graph data type? If so, consider using the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) java graph library.